# Python 3 tuple iteration. Bug or intended behaviour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

If I have a parent list containing a single iterable item, either a list or a tuple, and I iterate over the parent list, the loop runs once and I get the child list or tuple as the single parameter, but if I use a tuple for the parent, the loop actually iterates over the child, looping several, as shown in the code snippets below. Is this the intended behaviour or does it need to be reported as a bug?

Many thanks,
David Shaw

```
test = [(1, 'one')]
for i in test:
    print(test)
```

Output:

```
(1, 'one)
```

python

```
test = ((2, 'two'))
for i in test:
    print(test)
```

Output:

```
2
'two'
```

Comment: `test = ((2, 'two'))` did not create a nested tuple, print it out, and you'll see it was the same as `test = (2, 'two')`. If you wanted to create a 1 length tuple, you needed to put a trailing comma. Quirks of tuples you can call it. `test = ((2, 'two'),)`

Comment: if theres no comma, the value "test" is not actually a tuple, it is counted like a expression and only returns `(2,'two')`

Comment: try `test = ((2, 'two'),)` and you will get what you want. You need the comma

Comment: `((2, 'two')) == (2, 'two') ` is `True` but `((2, 'two'),) == (2, 'two')` is `False`

Comment: Try test = ((2, 'two),)

Answer (score 5):

Parentheses don’t make tuples. Commas make tuples.  These are all the same value of integer 1:

```
x = ((1))
x = (1)
x = 1
```

Compare to:

```
x = ((1,'one'))
x = (1,'one')
x = 1,'one'
```

All make a single 2-tuple.

Use the following to group a 2-tuple inside a 1-tuple:

```
x = (1,'one'),
```

Comment: `Parentheses don’t make tuples. Commas make tuples`. I've been using Python for 6 years now and I did not know this! Thank you.

Comment: @Gabriel Well, the one exception is `x = ()` makes an empty tuple, but otherwise parentheses are only needed for correct grouping.